# Question about admin role

Tags: 8

Does the admin role always has access to everything ?

Because even if my AccessResult returns false, my admin still have acces to it (but it's perfectly working for the other roles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the admin role, no. But user 1 does have access to everything, yes.

This is the function responsible, [`User::hasPermission`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AhasPermission/8.6.x), you can see the unconditional access check at the top:

```
public function hasPermission($permission) {
    // User #1 has all privileges.
    if ((int) $this->id() === 1) {
      return TRUE;
    }

    return $this->getRoleStorage()->isPermissionInRoles($permission, $this->getRoles());
  }
```

Comment: Where can I see this ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I think I have this result for my other admin (user 4), I just want to check if there's also my user 4 (but it shouldn't, if it's drupal base config)